# How to show tab urls in the console log from a fiefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, mozilla

I am trying to output all tabs in the current window by creating a firefox extension. It seems to be perfect to me, but still not able to get the output in the log. I am testing it as temporary addon from about:debugging.

I even tried to run the js code under "content_scripts", though it doesn't seem to be changing any content, but should run in the background. none of them works. Just want to know what I am missing

JavaScript

```
  function logTabs(tabs) {
  for (let tab of tabs) {
    // tab.url requires the `tabs` permission
    console.log(tab.url);
  }
}

function onError(error) {
  console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
}

var querying = browser.tabs.query({{currentWindow: true}});
querying.then(logTabs, onError);
```

Manifest

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Tablog",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "Prints the all tabs url in he console",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/icon48.png"
  },


   "background": {
    "scripts": ["tablog.js"]

  },

    "permissions": [
     "<all_urls>",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
]

}
```

Comment: `{{currentWindow: true}}` doesn't seem right. Also, what console are you looking at to expect the result? It will be the background page's console, not current page's console.

Comment: Thank you so much, you answered my query. I was looking at the wrong console.